# How to get the Google Map based on users input given by textbox?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i want to display google map on my asp.net web application. when the user enter longitude and latitude value on text boxes, after clicking on show google map button, I have to display appropriate location in Google map as like this link is working https://www.google.com/maps/@37.0625,-95.677068,4z

Answer (score 0):

I think you should can either use the [Javascript v3 API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial), which gives you more control of your maps.
All you need to do is to replace the `center` to your center.

Or you can use the [Google Maps Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide), where you can easily replace the `&q=` query to fit your needs.

Comment: to activate the api access, is it necessary to pay money?

Comment: no, it has a free quota for embed api. and I believe you don't need a key for Javascript v3 API now. The quota is pretty big and you should be fine if you are not crawling their site.

Comment: i wanna send coordinates(longitude and latitude) from GPRS module to my ASP.NET website (using localhost) how could i do this?? My main focus is to show these cordinates on google map (to get value on textboxes). and then stores these values on database SQLSERVER.              if u have any idea about this so please do help me.